# NumPy: how to quickly normalize many vectors?

Tags: python, vector, numpy, normalization

How can a list of vectors be elegantly normalized, in NumPy?

Here is an example that does *not* work:

```
from numpy import *

vectors = array([arange(10), arange(10)])  # All x's, then all y's
norms = apply_along_axis(linalg.norm, 0, vectors)

# Now, what I was expecting would work:
print vectors.T / norms  # vectors.T has 10 elements, as does norms, but this does not work
```

The last operation yields "shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape".

How can the normalization of the 2D vectors in `vectors` be elegantly done, with NumPy?

**Edit**: Why does the above not work while adding a dimension to `norms` does work (as per my answer below)?

Comment: FYI, a commenter may have a faster method, I edited my answer with more detail.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well, unless I missed something, this does work:

```
vectors / norms
```

The problem in your suggestion is the broadcasting rules.

```
vectors  # shape 2, 10
norms  # shape 10
```

The shape do not have the same length! So the rule is to first extend the small shape by one on the **left**:

```
norms  # shape 1,10
```

You can do that manually by calling:

```
vectors / norms.reshape(1,-1)  # same as vectors/norms
```

If you wanted to compute `vectors.T/norms`, you would have to do the reshaping manually, as follows:

```
vectors.T / norms.reshape(-1,1)  # this works
```

Comment: why not just do (vectors/norms).T if the OP wants this transposed. It seems both simple and elegant to me.

Comment: Ah, ah!  so the dimension extension is done on the _left_: this indeed explains the observed behavior.  Thanks!

Answer (score 27):

## Computing the magnitude

I came across this question and became curious about your method for normalizing. I use a different method to compute the magnitudes. *Note: I also typically compute norms across the last index (rows in this case, not columns).*

```
magnitudes = np.sqrt((vectors ** 2).sum(-1))[..., np.newaxis]
```

Typically, however, I just normalize like so:

```
vectors /= np.sqrt((vectors ** 2).sum(-1))[..., np.newaxis]
```

## A time comparison

I ran a test to compare the times, and found that my method is faster by quite a bit, but [Freddie Witherdon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/315974/freddie-witherden)'s suggestion is even faster.

```
import numpy as np    
vectors = np.random.rand(100, 25)

# OP's
%timeit np.apply_along_axis(np.linalg.norm, 1, vectors)
# Output: 100 loops, best of 3: 2.39 ms per loop

# Mine
%timeit np.sqrt((vectors ** 2).sum(-1))[..., np.newaxis]
# Output: 10000 loops, best of 3: 13.8 us per loop

# Freddie's (from comment below)
%timeit np.sqrt(np.einsum('...i,...i', vectors, vectors))
# Output: 10000 loops, best of 3: 6.45 us per loop
```

Beware though, as this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18366008/310165) notes, there are some safety checks not happening with `einsum`, so you should be sure that the `dtype` of `vectors` is sufficient to store the square of the magnitudes accurately enough.

Comment: Interesting timing results (I obtain respectively 0.8 s and 1.4 s, with the more robust %timeit function of IPython), thanks!

Comment: I have found `np.sqrt(np.einsum('...i,...i', vectors, vectors))` to be ~4 times faster than Method 1 as given above.

Comment: @FreddieWitherden - Thanks for the comment, I didn't know about `einsum`. There's in interesting related SO question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365073/why-is-numpys-einsum-faster-than-numpys-built-in-functions  It will typically be faster, but may not be safe (depending on the `dtype` of the vector).

Comment: @FreddieWitherden, your method gives different (but `np.allclose`) values to mine.

Comment: @EOL - Thanks, I switched to ipython, and updated my answer. It turns out my HUGE array was giving some serious overhead. With a smaller one (in my new answer) the speed difference is much more noticeable.

Comment: @Geoff: The methods called "OP's" and "Mine" do not calculate the same thing (25 norms vs 100 norms). Thus, the order in which the elements are accessed differ, which can result in different speeds. The comparison should obviously be made on calculations that produce identical results. :)

Answer (score 16):

Alright: NumPy's array shape broadcast adds dimensions to the *left* of the array shape, not to its right. NumPy can however be instructed to add a dimension to the right of the `norms` array:

```
print vectors.T / norms[:, newaxis]
```

does work!

Comment: Just a note, I use `norms[..., np.newaxis]` in case the matrix is not just 2D. It would work with a 3D (or more) tensor as well.

Answer (score 11):

there is already a function in scikit learn:

```
import sklearn.preprocessing as preprocessing
norm =preprocessing.normalize(m, norm='l2')*
```

More info at:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html

Comment: Interesting information, but the question is explicitly about NumPy. It would be better put it in a comment to the original question.

Answer (score 6):

My preferred way to normalize vectors is by using numpy's inner1d to calculate their magnitudes. Here's what's been suggested so far compared to inner1d

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.core.umath_tests import inner1d
COUNT = 10**6 # 1 million points

points = np.random.random_sample((COUNT,3,))
A      = np.sqrt(np.einsum('...i,...i', points, points))
B      = np.apply_along_axis(np.linalg.norm, 1, points)   
C      = np.sqrt((points ** 2).sum(-1))
D      = np.sqrt((points*points).sum(axis=1))
E      = np.sqrt(inner1d(points,points))

print [np.allclose(E,x) for x in [A,B,C,D]] # [True, True, True, True]
```

Testing  performance with cProfile:

```
import cProfile
cProfile.run("np.sqrt(np.einsum('...i,...i', points, points))**0.5") # 3 function calls in 0.013 seconds
cProfile.run('np.apply_along_axis(np.linalg.norm, 1, points)')       # 9000018 function calls in 10.977 seconds
cProfile.run('np.sqrt((points ** 2).sum(-1))')                       # 5 function calls in 0.028 seconds
cProfile.run('np.sqrt((points*points).sum(axis=1))')                 # 5 function calls in 0.027 seconds
cProfile.run('np.sqrt(inner1d(points,points))')                      # 2 function calls in 0.009 seconds
```

inner1d computed the magnitudes a hair faster than einsum. So using inner1d to normalize:

```
n = points/np.sqrt(inner1d(points,points))[:,None]
cProfile.run('points/np.sqrt(inner1d(points,points))[:,None]') # 2 function calls in 0.026 seconds
```

Testing against scikit:

```
import sklearn.preprocessing as preprocessing
n_ = preprocessing.normalize(points, norm='l2')
cProfile.run("preprocessing.normalize(points, norm='l2')") # 47 function calls in 0.047 seconds
np.allclose(n,n_) # True
```

Conclusion: using inner1d seems to be the best option

Comment: For reference, the question actually calls for calculating the norm along the _first_ dimension, not the second (see the caveat added to Geoff's answer). How would this change the results? There might be an impact, because of the way memory is accessed, especially if you have a larger second dimension (instead of 3 in your example).

Answer (score 1):

For the two-dimensional case, using `np.hypot(vectors[:,0],vectors[:,1])` looks to be faster than Freddie Witherden's `np.sqrt(np.einsum('...i,...i', vectors, vectors))` for calculating the magnitudes. (Referencing answer by Geoff)

```
import numpy as np

# Generate array of 2D vectors.
vectors = np.random.random((1000,2))

# Using Freddie's
%timeit np.sqrt(np.einsum('...i,...i', vectors, vectors))
# Output: 11.1 µs ± 173 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

# Using numpy.hypot()
%timeit np.hypot(vectors[:,0], vectors[:,1])
# Output: 6.81 µs ± 112 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

To get the normalised vectors then do:

```
vectors /= np.hypot(vectors[:,0], vectors[:,1])
```