# fast python numpy where functionality?

Tags: python, performance, for-loop, numpy, where-clause

I am using numpy's where function many times inside several `for` loops, but it becomes way too slow. Are there any ways to perform this functionality faster? I read you should try to do in-line for loops, as well as make local variables for functions before the `for` loops, but nothing seems to improve speed by much (< 1%). The `len(UNIQ_IDS)` ~ 800. `emiss_data` and `obj_data` are numpy ndarrays with shape = (2600,5200). I've used `import profile` to get a handle on where the bottlenecks are, and `where` in `for` loops is a big one.

```
import numpy as np
max = np.max
where = np.where
MAX_EMISS = [max(emiss_data[where(obj_data == i)]) for i in UNIQ_IDS)]
```

Comment: Are you calculating `UNIQ_IDS` in this script or is this predetermined?

Comment: UNIQ_IDS is predetermined...a list of ints of len = 800. This is just a code snippet, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It turns out that a pure Python loop can be much much faster than NumPy indexing (or calls to np.where) in this case.

Consider the following alternatives:

```
import numpy as np
import collections
import itertools as IT

shape = (2600,5200)
# shape = (26,52)
emiss_data = np.random.random(shape)
obj_data = np.random.random_integers(1, 800, size=shape)
UNIQ_IDS = np.unique(obj_data)

def using_where():
    max = np.max
    where = np.where
    MAX_EMISS = [max(emiss_data[where(obj_data == i)]) for i in UNIQ_IDS]
    return MAX_EMISS

def using_index():
    max = np.max
    MAX_EMISS = [max(emiss_data[obj_data == i]) for i in UNIQ_IDS]
    return MAX_EMISS

def using_max():
    MAX_EMISS = [(emiss_data[obj_data == i]).max() for i in UNIQ_IDS]
    return MAX_EMISS

def using_loop():
    result = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for val, idx in IT.izip(emiss_data.ravel(), obj_data.ravel()):
        result[idx].append(val)
    return [max(result[idx]) for idx in UNIQ_IDS]

def using_sort():
    uind = np.digitize(obj_data.ravel(), UNIQ_IDS) - 1
    vals = uind.argsort()
    count = np.bincount(uind)
    start = 0
    end = 0
    out = np.empty(count.shape[0])
    for ind, x in np.ndenumerate(count):
        end += x
        out[ind] = np.max(np.take(emiss_data, vals[start:end]))
        start += x
    return out

def using_split():
    uind = np.digitize(obj_data.ravel(), UNIQ_IDS) - 1
    vals = uind.argsort()
    count = np.bincount(uind)
    return [np.take(emiss_data, item).max()
            for item in np.split(vals, count.cumsum())[:-1]]

for func in (using_index, using_max, using_loop, using_sort, using_split):
    assert using_where() == func()
```

Here are the benchmarks, with `shape = (2600,5200)`:

```
In [57]: %timeit using_loop()
1 loops, best of 3: 9.15 s per loop

In [90]: %timeit using_sort()
1 loops, best of 3: 9.33 s per loop

In [91]: %timeit using_split()
1 loops, best of 3: 9.33 s per loop

In [61]: %timeit using_index()
1 loops, best of 3: 63.2 s per loop

In [62]: %timeit using_max()
1 loops, best of 3: 64.4 s per loop

In [58]: %timeit using_where()
1 loops, best of 3: 112 s per loop
```

Thus `using_loop` (pure Python) turns out to be more than 11x faster than `using_where`.

I'm not entirely sure why pure Python is faster than NumPy here. My guess is that the pure Python version zips (yes, pun intended) through both arrays once. It leverages the fact that despite all the fancy indexing, *we really just want to visit each value once*. Thus it side-steps the issue with having to determine exactly which group each value in `emiss_data` falls in. But this is just vague speculation. I didn't know it would be faster until I benchmarked.

Comment: what is 'list' in using_loop?

Comment: [`collections.defaultdict(list)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) creates a dict-like object which returns a list as the default value.

Answer (score 8):

Can use `np.unique` with `return_index`:

```
def using_sort():
    #UNIQ_IDS,uind=np.unique(obj_data, return_inverse=True)
    uind= np.digitize(obj_data.ravel(), UNIQ_IDS) - 1
    vals=uind.argsort()
    count=np.bincount(uind)

    start=0
    end=0

    out=np.empty(count.shape[0])
    for ind,x in np.ndenumerate(count):
        end+=x
        out[ind]=np.max(np.take(emiss_data,vals[start:end]))
        start+=x
    return out
```

Using @unutbu's answer as a baseline for `shape = (2600,5200)`:

```
np.allclose(using_loop(),using_sort())
True

%timeit using_loop()
1 loops, best of 3: 12.3 s per loop

#With np.unique inside the definition
%timeit using_sort()
1 loops, best of 3: 9.06 s per loop

#With np.unique outside the definition 
%timeit using_sort()
1 loops, best of 3: 2.75 s per loop

#Using @Jamie's suggestion for uind
%timeit using_sort()
1 loops, best of 3: 6.74 s per loop
```

Comment: I think if `UNIQ_IDS` really has the unique entries of `obj_data` precalculated, you can call `np.digitize(obj_data, UNIQ_IDS) - 1` to get the same result as your `uind` in about half the time.

Comment: Your method is really clever but unfortunately I'm unable to obtain the same speed gain. (I've added a benchmark for `using_sort` when run on my machine in my post. For me, `using_loop` is still slightly faster.) Perhaps the difference is due to version of Python, or OS? I'm using Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 11.10. What are you using?

Comment: @unutbu I am using OSX and a fully updated anaconda install (it does have accelerate which I know has screwed up timings in the past). I also tried with python 2.7.4 and numpy 1.7.1 on the OSX box and I obtained the same results; however, I tried on a Ubuntu box with an AMD chip with numpy 1.6.1 and found the timings to be equivalent. I hate to keep posting [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365073/why-is-numpys-einsum-faster-than-numpys-built-in-functions) question, but there seems to be something going on with timings that I do not quite understand.

Answer (score 5):

I believe the fastest way to accomplish this is to use the `groupby()` operations in the `pandas` package. Comparing to @Ophion's `using_sort()` function, Pandas is about a factor of 10 faster:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

shape = (2600,5200)
emiss_data = np.random.random(shape)
obj_data = np.random.random_integers(1, 800, size=shape)
UNIQ_IDS = np.unique(obj_data)

def using_sort():
    #UNIQ_IDS,uind=np.unique(obj_data, return_inverse=True)
    uind= np.digitize(obj_data.ravel(), UNIQ_IDS) - 1
    vals=uind.argsort()
    count=np.bincount(uind)

    start=0
    end=0

    out=np.empty(count.shape[0])
    for ind,x in np.ndenumerate(count):
        end+=x
        out[ind]=np.max(np.take(emiss_data,vals[start:end]))
        start+=x
    return out

def using_pandas():
    return pd.Series(emiss_data.ravel()).groupby(obj_data.ravel()).max()

print('same results:', np.allclose(using_pandas(), using_sort()))
# same results: True

%timeit using_sort()
# 1 loops, best of 3: 3.39 s per loop

%timeit using_pandas()
# 1 loops, best of 3: 397 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 3):

Can't you just do

```
emiss_data[obj_data == i]
```

? I'm not sure why you're using `where` at all.

Comment: Well that does work and is an improvement by ~45%. Thanks. I guess I'm using where because I'm so used to IDL and am trying to convert to python. However, it is still very slow. It takes 75 seconds to do this 800 times, whereas IDL would have it done in 2 seconds tops. And what if you actually need the locations/indices for future operations? I don't imagine this would be very efficient if you used it several times in a for loop instead of one where statement in the for loop.

Comment: It seems like there ought to be a way to group `emiss_data` values by `obj_data` values with numpy built-ins. I haven't found one, though.

Comment: You can use `np.lexsort`; however, the `lexsort` itself is the bottleneck leading to a suboptimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning a tuple is much faster than assigning a list, according to [Are tuples more efficient than lists in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68630/are-tuples-more-efficient-than-lists-in-python), so maybe just by building a tuple instead of a list, this will improve efficiency.

Comment: I doubt it. Tuples have advantages in some cases, but none of them apply here. That question (or rather, the accepted answer over there) does not show that tuples are faster to construct, it shows that *literal* tuples can be constructed once and used multiple times. And even if tuple creation *was* faster than list creation, there's no way that's the bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

If `obj_data` consists of relatively small integers, you can use `numpy.maximum.at` (since v1.8.0):

```
def using_maximumat():
    n = np.max(UNIQ_IDS) + 1
    temp = np.full(n, -np.inf)
    np.maximum.at(temp, obj_data, emiss_data)
    return temp[UNIQ_IDS]
```