# Improve performance python matrix

Tags: python, performance, numpy, matrix

I have a large matrix (shape: 2e6, 6) containing geophysical data. I have 3 `for` loops before I search for values in the matrix to assign my variables.

My first solution is with `np.where`. It's way too slow! I read [it would be better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18452591/fast-python-numpy-where-functionality) to use another `for` loop to improve performance. However, the code I came up with is even slightly slower.

Does someone have an idea how to improve the performance, please?

First Solution (`np.where`)

```
for lat in LATS:
    for lon in LONS:
        for depth in range(1,401,1):

            node_point_line = matrix[np.where( (matrix[:,0]==lat) * (matrix[:,1]==lon) * (matrix[:,2]==depth) )][0]

            var1 = node_point_line[3]
            var2 = node_point_line[4]
            var3 = node_point_line[5]
            ...
```

Second Solution (extra `for` loop)

```
for lat in LATS:
    for lon in LONS:
        for depth in range(1,401,1):

            matrix_flat = matrix.flatten()
            for i in range( len( matrix_flat )):
                if matrix_flat[i]==lat and matrix_flat[i+1]==lon and matrix_flat[i+2]==depth:
                    var1 = matrix_flat[i+3]
                    var2 = matrix_flat[i+4]
                    var3 = matrix_flat[i+5]
                    ...
```

Again, both solutions are too slow. I avoid Fortran or C++ (I know it's faster). Any suggestions?

Comment: It's not so much that `where` is slow, but that you are doing it many times.  You are iterating over 3 levels.  What are you doing with `var1,var2,var3`?

Comment: I use those variables to calculate an integral over depth, for each LAT/LON point.

Comment: @Johngoldenboy looks like there is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here: you ask to optimize specific part of an algo (lookups) while trying to solve a bigger problem. I'd suggest opening a separate question (probably on [CS](http://cs.stackexchange.com/) website) asking for a faster algorithm of calculating integral. I think what you do is extremely suboptimal, but it's hard to reason as I don't know what exactly are you trying to do.

Comment: In a `numpy` we try avoid loops, especially multiple levels.  We push the iterations onto fast compiled functions, and only iterate when that is impossible.

Comment: may be the one of the approaches can be to use jit compilation by @numba (http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.17.0/user/jit.html). It can give acceleration for such type problems.

Answer (score 0):

How big are your `LATS` and `LONS` arrays? Even if they are one element long, then your program have to perform approximately `1*1*400*1e6*3 ~ 1.2e9` operations, which is way too much. Even when implemented properly in C++ it may take a second or more.

I think you should optimize your algorithm. It's not really clear what you're trying to do, but my guess is that you're trying to find any place in a matrix which has latitude in your `LATS` list, longitude in your `LONS` list and depth between 1 and 400. Exchange places of the loops: run along the matrix in the outer loop and then check that all three conditions hold. Afterwards, you'll be able to replace list of latitudes with `set` of latitudes, and `set` lookup is much more faster than list lookup.

Comment: I need to calculate an integral over depth, using var1 to var3. Both LAT and LON have a size of ~100, both are already a list(set(matrix[;,1])). You may be right to re-organise my for loops.

Comment: If both arrays are 100 long, then amount of operations is enormous: `100*100*400*1e6*3 ~ 1e13`. It's hours, if not days, depending on hardware and optimizations.

Comment: Exactly. That's why I need to optimize it.

Answer (score 0):

Given the numbers it should be reasonably efficient to just `lexsort` your data array. That's 2 seconds invested in the beginning removing all the `where` statements.

The code snippet assumes that `LATS` and `LONS` are sorted:

```
order = np.lexsort([matrix.T][2::-1] # takes < 2 sec
sorted = matrix[order, :]

data_per_lat = np.split(sorted, sorted[:, 0].searchsorted(LATS[1:], axis=0)
for lat, dpla in zip(LATS, data_per_lat):
    data_per_lon = np.split(dpla, dpla[:, 1].searchsorted[LONS[1:], axis=0)
    for lon, dplo in zip(LONS, data_per_lon):
        depth, var1, var2, var3 = dplo.T[2:]
        # the variables are now vectors, containing all data matching lon and lat sorted by depth
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can compress your starting matrix with a vectorized process, which will make your looping faster.

```
DPTH=np.arange(1,401,1)
mask=np.in1d(matrix[:,0],LATS) * np.in1d(matrix[:,1],LONS) * np.in1d(matrix[:,2],DPTH)
matrix_masked=matrix[mask]
```

Then just `for` loop over `matrix_masked` either by `nditer` (complicated) or by

```
for i in range(matrix_masked.shape[0]):
    var1 = matrix_masked[i,3]
   . . .
```