# Multiplying nth column in 2D array by nth array in 3D array using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2D and a 3D numpy array and would like to multiply each column of the 2D array by its respective array. Eg multiplying

```
[[[1. 1.]
  [1. 1.]
  [1. 1.]]

 [[1. 1.]
  [1. 1.]
  [1. 1.]]]
```

by

```
[[ 5  6]
 [ 4  7]
 [ 8 10]]
```

gives

```
[[[ 5.  5.]
  [ 4.  4.]
  [ 8.  8.]]

 [[ 6.  6.]
  [ 7.  7.]
  [10. 10.]]]
```

My code currently is:

```
three_d_array = np.ones([2,3,2])
two_d_array = np.array([(5,6), (4,7), (8,10)])

list_of_arrays = []

for i in range(np.shape(two_d_array)[1]):
    mult = np.einsum('ij, i -> ij', three_d_array[i], two_d_array[:,i])
    list_of_arrays.append(mult)

stacked_array = np.stack(list_of_arrays, 0)
```

using an answer from [Multiplying across in a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18522216/multiplying-across-in-a-numpy-array)
but is there a way of doing it without a for loop? Thanks a lot, Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `nth` column in `2D` array would be the second axis and by `nth` array in `3D` array, it seems you meant the `2D` slice along the first axis. So, the idea would be to align the first axis along `three_d_array` and second axis along `two_d_array`. Out of the remaining axes, the first axis from `two_d_array` seems to be aligned to the second one off `three_d_array`.

So, to solve it we could use two methods and functions.

**Approach #1**

Transpose `2D` array and then extend dimensions to `3D` to have one singleton one at the end and then perform elementwise multiplication with other `3D` array, leveraging `broadcasting` for a vectorized solution -

```
three_d_array*two_d_array.T[...,None]
```

**Approach #2**

With `np.einsum` -

```
np.einsum('ijk,ji->ijk',three_d_array, two_d_array)
```

Comment: Thanks! I clearly haven't quite got my head around einsum yet but that works perfectly!