# Multiply vector with matrix element wise

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have a (n,1) np-array, for example `array([1 2 3])` that I would like to multiply element wise with a np-matrix (n,m), for example `array([[1 1 1], [2 2 2], [3 3 3]])` so that I will get:

```
array([[1 1 1], [4 4 4], [9 9 9]])
```

How can I do that?

I have tried with np.multiply and np.dot.

Comment: Duplicate of  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18522216/multiplying-across-in-a-numpy-array

Answer (score 1):

Reshape your vector so that it contains 3 rows instead of 3 columns:

```
v = np.array([1, 2, 3])
m = np.array([[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]])

u = v.reshape(*v.shape, 1)
u * m  # results in [[1, 1, 1], [4, 4, 4], [9, 9, 9]]
```