# Custom loss function in keras involving huge matrix multiplication

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, keras-layer, loss-function

I am having difficulty writing the custom loss function in Keras. I have layer weights "W" and a matrix "M".  I want to do the following operation trace((W * M) * W') to compute my loss function. Trace is the sum of the diagonal elements. In numpy, I would have done the following:

```
np.trace(np.dot(np.dot(W,M),W.T))) or 

def custom_regularizer(W,M):
    sum_reg = 0
    for i in range(W.shape[1]):
        for j in range(i,W.shape[1]):
            vector = W[:,i] - W[:,j]
            sum_reg = sum_reg + M[i,j] * (LA.norm(vector)**2)
    return sum_reg
```

For keras, I have written following loss function

```
def custom_loss(W):

  def lossFunction(y_true,y_pred):    
    loss = tf.trace(K.dot(K.dot(W,K.constant(M)),K.transpose(W)))
    return loss

return lossFunction
```

The problem is that keras is computing the whole outer matrix whose dimension is 200000 * 200000, giving memory error. Is there any way by which I can just get the sum of diagonal elements without doing the whole matrix computation.

How to do the same as keras loss function ?

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18854425/what-is-the-best-way-to-compute-the-trace-of-a-matrix-product-in-numpy/18854776#18854776) for some pointers

Comment: @learner Thanks. It worked.

Comment: I'm gonna post the link as the answer, so that we have one less unanswered question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow some clever tricks to compute the trace, you should not be running out of memory. For instance, you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18854425/what-is-the-best-way-to-compute-the-trace-of-a-matrix-product-in-numpy/18854776#18854776).