# Efficient columnwise correlation coefficient calculation

Tags: performance, numpy, correlation, pearson-correlation

**Original question**

I am correlating row P of size n to every column of matrix O of size n×m. I crafted the following code:

```py
import numpy as np

def ColumnWiseCorrcoef(O, P):
    n = P.size
    DO = O - (np.sum(O, 0) / np.double(n))
    DP = P - (np.sum(P) / np.double(n))
    return np.dot(DP, DO) / np.sqrt(np.sum(DO ** 2, 0) * np.sum(DP ** 2))
```

It is more efficient than the naive approach:

```py
def ColumnWiseCorrcoefNaive(O, P):
    return np.corrcoef(P,O.T)[0,1:O[0].size+1]
```

Here are the timings I get with numpy-1.7.1-MKL on an Intel core:

```py
O = np.reshape(np.random.rand(100000), (1000,100))
P = np.random.rand(1000)

%timeit -n 1000 A = ColumnWiseCorrcoef(O, P)
1000 loops, best of 3: 787 us per loop
%timeit -n 1000 B = ColumnWiseCorrcoefNaive(O, P)
1000 loops, best of 3: 2.96 ms per loop
```

Now the question: can you suggest an even faster version of the code for this problem? Squeezing out additional 20% would be great.

**UPDATE May 2017**

After quite some time I got back to this problem, re-run and extended the task and the tests.

1. Using einsum, I have extended the code to the case where P is not a row but a matrix. So the task is correlating all columns of O to all columns of P.
2. Being curious on how the same problem can be solved in different languages commonly used for scientific computing, I implemented it (with help from other people) in MATLAB, Julia, and R. MATLAB and Julia are the fastest, and they have a dedicated routine to compute columnwise correlation. R also has a dedicated routine but is the slowest.
3. In the current version of numpy (1.12.1 from Anaconda) einsum still wins over dedicated functions I used.

All the scripts and timings are available at https://github.com/ikizhvatov/efficient-columnwise-correlation.

Comment: Can `O` and `P` be changed? Also these methods rely heavily on the BLAS library linked to numpy, I would suggest using some sort of optimized BLAS if you have not already.

Comment: @Ophion, `P` can be changed, `O` cannot. I am using numpy linked to Intel MKL from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/.

Comment: Can't test it right now, but there may be some marginal improvement if you try `np.einsum('ij,ij->j', DO, DO)` instead of `np.sum(DO ** 2, 0)`, and `np.dot(DP, DP)` instead of `np.sum(DP ** 2)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can introduce `np.einsum` to this; however, your milage may [vary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365073/why-is-numpys-einsum-faster-than-numpys-built-in-functions) depending on your compilation and if it makes use of SSE2 or not. The extra `einsum` calls to replace summation operations might seem extraneous, but numpy ufuncs do not make use of SSE2 until numpy 1.8 while `einsum` does and we can avoid a few `if` statements.

Running this on a opteron core with intel mkl blas I get a odd result as I would expect the `dot` call to take the majority of the time.

```py
def newColumnWiseCorrcoef(O, P):
    n = P.size
    DO = O - (np.einsum('ij->j',O) / np.double(n))
    P -= (np.einsum('i->',P) / np.double(n))
    tmp = np.einsum('ij,ij->j',DO,DO)
    tmp *= np.einsum('i,i->',P,P)          #Dot or vdot doesnt really change much.
    return np.dot(P, DO) / np.sqrt(tmp)

O = np.reshape(np.random.rand(100000), (1000,100))
P = np.random.rand(1000)

old = ColumnWiseCorrcoef(O,P)
new = newColumnWiseCorrcoef(O,P)

np.allclose(old,new)
True

%timeit ColumnWiseCorrcoef(O,P)
100 loops, best of 3: 1.52ms per loop

%timeit newColumnWiseCorrcoef(O,P)
1000 loops, best of 3: 518us per loop
```

Running this with a intel system with intel mkl again I get something more reasonable/expected:

```py
%timeit ColumnWiseCorrcoef(O,P)
1000 loops, best of 3: 524 µs per loop

%timeit newColumnWiseCorrcoef(O,P)
1000 loops, best of 3: 354 µs per loop
```

Again on the intel machine with something a bit bigger:

```py
O = np.random.rand(1E5,1E3)
P = np.random.rand(1E5)

%timeit ColumnWiseCorrcoef(O,P)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.33 s per loop

%timeit newColumnWiseCorrcoef(O,P)
1 loops, best of 3: 791 ms per loop
```

Comment: Is the `tmp = ...; tmp *= ...` supposed to save time? I've seen others do it as well an I don't see the advantage over `tmp = ... * ...`.

Comment: I found this solution very helpful, I wondered if there was a way to extend it to calculate a regression residual without sacrificing much in terms of speed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a *less* efficient solution, but it is highly-readable and just one line of code:

`np.einsum("ij,i->j", spst.zscore(A), spst.zscore(B)) / A.shape[0]`

And, if one wants `B` to be a matrix not a vector, and to compute correlations for corresponding pairs of columns, it is easily modified to:

`np.einsum("ij,ij->j", spst.zscore(A), spst.zscore(B)) / A.shape[0]`

According to my timing test on my iMac with 2.8 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i5, it is roughly 3x slower:

```
import scipy.stats as spst

def ColumnWiseCorrcoef(O, P):
    n = P.size
    DO = O - (np.sum(O, 0) / np.double(n))
    DP = P - (np.sum(P) / np.double(n))
    return np.dot(DP, DO) / np.sqrt(np.sum(DO ** 2, 0) * np.sum(DP ** 2))

def newColumnWiseCorrcoef(O, P):
    n = P.size
    DO = O - (np.einsum('ij->j',O) / np.double(n))
    P -= (np.einsum('i->',P) / np.double(n))
    tmp = np.einsum('ij,ij->j',DO,DO)
    tmp *= np.einsum('i,i->',P,P)          #Dot or vdot doesnt really change much.
    return np.dot(P, DO) / np.sqrt(tmp)

def OneLineColumnWiseCorrcoef(A, B):
    return np.einsum("ij,i->j", spst.zscore(A), spst.zscore(B)) / A.shape[0]

O = np.reshape(np.random.rand(100000), (1000,100))
P = np.random.rand(1000)

old = ColumnWiseCorrcoef(O,P)
new = OneLineColumnWiseCorrcoef(O, P)
np.allclose(old,new)
True

%timeit ColumnWiseCorrcoef(O,P)
# 325 µs ± 19.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

%timeit newColumnWiseCorrcoef(O,P)
# 274 µs ± 713 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

%timeit OneLineColumnWiseCorrcoef(O,P)
# 1.02 ms ± 4.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```