# BASH, Dihedral angle with four points

Tags: bash, awk, calc

Points:

```
A -2.08576        1.76533       -0.46417
B -0.95929        0.87554        0.03365
C  0.28069        1.66193        0.42640
D  0.62407        2.22927       -0.44649
```

So far, I have done:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk 'NR==1' $FILE > LINEA
awk 'NR==1' $FILE > LINEB
awk 'NR==1' $FILE > LINEC
awk 'NR==1' $FILE > LINED
x1=`awk '{print $2}' LINEA` # x1
y1=`awk '{print $3}' LINEA` # y1
z1=`awk '{print $4}' LINEA` # z1
x2=`awk '{print $2}' LINEB` # x2
y2=`awk '{print $3}' LINEB` # y2
z2=`awk '{print $4}' LINEB` # z2
x3=`awk '{print $2}' LINEC` # x3
y3=`awk '{print $3}' LINEC` # y3
z3=`awk '{print $4}' LINEC` # z3
x4=`awk '{print $2}' LINED` # x4
y4=`awk '{print $3}' LINED` # y4
z4=`awk '{print $4}' LINED` # z4
v1x=`calc "($x1)-($x2)" | sed 's/^\t//g'`
v1y=`calc "($y1)-($y2)" | sed 's/^\t//g'`
v1z=`calc "($z1)-($z2)" | sed 's/^\t//g'`
v2x=`calc "($x4)-($x3)" | sed 's/^\t//g'`
v2y=`calc "($y4)-($y3)" | sed 's/^\t//g'`
v2z=`calc "($z4)-($z3)" | sed 's/^\t//g'`
v1mag=`calc "sqrt(($v1x)**2+($v1y)**2+($v1z)**2)" | sed 's/^\t//g'`
v2mag=`calc "sqrt(($v2x)**2+($v2y)**2+($v2z)**2)" | sed 's/^\t//g'`
calc "acos((($v1x)/($v1mag))*(($v2x)/($v2mag))+(($v1y)/($v1mag))*(($v2y)/($v2mag))+(($v1z)/($v1mag))*(($v2z)/($v2mag)))*180/3.141592653589793" | sed 's/^\t//g' | sed 's/^~//g'
calc "acos((($x1)*($x4)+($y1)*($y4)+($z1)*($z4))/(sqrt(($x1)**2+($y1)**2+($z1)**2)*sqrt(($x4)**2+($y4)**2+($z4)**2)))*180/3.141592653589793" | sed 's/^\t//g' | sed 's/^~//g'
```

I have found these related links [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19729831/angle-between-3-points-in-3d-space), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20305272/dihedral-torsion-angle-from-four-points-in-cartesian-coordinates-in-python/20652734?noredirect=1#comment80249219_20652734) and [3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_angle#Calculation_of_a_dihedral_angle).

The referenced value is `58.7 $^{o}$`

The value that I get is: `70.62525933704842342761 $^{o}$` and `64.23010091217222985704 $^{o}$`

**Someone knows what would the best algorithm be to obtain it properly?**

Comment: so, the result should be `-58.7` ?

Comment: `bash` is really the wrong language to use here. You could (almost) do the entire thing with a single `awk` script, but using a proper general-purpose programming language would be far easier.

Comment: did you deliberately mean to redirect only the first line of the sample data into each of the files `LINE[A-D]` ? Plenty easy to do in one process of `awk`. Good luck.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yes, it is, I found it with a graphic tool

Comment: @shellter It is part of a big code. But thanks for your friendly comment.

Comment: @chepner , yes, I completely agree, I would prefer to do it with C++. But, my big issue is that I do not know what would the best algorithm be to find the torsion angle and I am also not skillful with `awk`.

Comment: "what would the best algo be to find the torsion angle" : Apparently there are numerous ways to calculate it : See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20305272/dihedral-torsion-angle-from-four-points-in-cartesian-coordinates-in-python . Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your refined shell code elsewhere in this thread, I've transcribed that into an `awk` solution as well. As people seem to have found the `_docd` version of use, I will include that at the end. I'm also including a debug version (in the middle of the reply).

```
cat torsion2.awk
```

-

```
#!/bin/awk -f  
BEGIN {
  # dbg=0 # turns off dbg output
  # see below for debug version of this script
}
function acos(x)  { return atan2((1.-x^2)^0.5,x) }    
NR==1 {x1=$2; y1=$3; z1=$4}
NR==2 {x2=$2; y2=$3; z2=$4}
NR==3 {x3=$2; y3=$3; z3=$4}
NR==4 {
  x4=$2; y4=$3; z4=$4  
  # all of this code below is only executed when you read in the 4th line
  # because then you have all the data
  #
  v1x=x2-x1 ; v1y=y2-y1 ; v1z=z2-z1     #plane1
  v2x=x3-x2 ; v2y=y3-y2 ; v2z=z3-z2     #plane1
  v3x=x2-x3 ; v3y=y2-y3 ; v3z=z2-z3     #plane2
  v4x=x3-x4 ; v4y=y3-y4 ; v4z=z3-z4     #plane2

  plane1_x=(v1y*v2z)-(v1z*v2y)  # normal vector 1
  plane1_y=(v2x*v1z)-(v2z*v1x)  # normal vector 1
  plane1_z=(v1x*v2y)-(v1y*v2x)  # normal vector 1
  plane2_x=(v3y*v4z)-(v3z*v4y)  # normal vector 2
  plane2_y=(v4x*v3z)-(v4z*v3x)  # normal vector 2
  plane2_z=(v3x*v4y)-(v3y*v4x)  # normal vector 2

  v1mag=sqrt(((plane1_x)**2)+((plane1_y)**2)+((plane1_z)**2)) # magnitude normal vector 1
  v2mag=sqrt(((plane2_x)**2)+((plane2_y)**2)+((plane2_z)**2)) # magnitude normal vector 2
  vn1x=(plane1_x)/(v1mag) ; vn1y=(plane1_y)/(v1mag) ; vn1z=(plane1_z)/(v1mag) # normalization normal vector 1
  vn2x=(plane2_x)/(v2mag) ; vn2y=(plane2_y)/(v2mag) ; vn2z=(plane2_z)/(v2mag) # normalization normal vector 2

  print acos((vn1x*vn2x)+(vn1y*vn2y)+(vn1z*vn2z))*180/3.141592653589793
}
```

Once the file is saved, you must mark the script as executable:

```
chmod +x ./torsion2.awk
```

Then you can run it with the sample data supplied:

```
./torsion2.awk data.txt
```

The output is

```
58.6892
```

---

Here is the full debug version. I needed it because I had editing errors  like changing `y2=$3` to just `y=$3`! (These things happen ;-/ )

```
cat torsion2_debug.awk
#!/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
  dbg=1   # turns on dbg output
  # dbg=0 # turns off dbg output
}
function acos(x)  { return atan2((1.-x^2)^0.5,x) }

NR==1 {x1=$2; y1=$3; z1=$4}
NR==2 {x2=$2; y2=$3; z2=$4}
NR==3 {x3=$2; y3=$3; z3=$4}
NR==4 {
  x4=$2; y4=$3; z4=$4

  if (dbg) {
    print "x1="x1 "\ty1="y1 "\tz1=" z1
    print "x2="x2 "\ty2="y2 "\tz2=" z2
    print "x3="x3 "\ty3="y3 "\tz3=" z3
    print "x4="x4 "\ty4="y4 "\tz4=" z4
  }

  # all of this code below is only executed when you read in the 4th line
  # because then you have all the data
  #
  v1x=x2-x1 ; v1y=y2-y1 ; v1z=z2-z1     #plane1
  v2x=x3-x2 ; v2y=y3-y2 ; v2z=z3-z2     #plane1
  v3x=x2-x3 ; v3y=y2-y3 ; v3z=z2-z3     #plane2
  v4x=x3-x4 ; v4y=y3-y4 ; v4z=z3-z4     #plane2

  if (dbg) {
    print "#dbg: v1x="v1x "\tv1y=" v1y "\tv1z="v1z
    print "#dbg: v2x="v2x "\tv2y=" v2y "\tv2z="v2z
    print "#dbg: v3x="v3x "\tv3y=" v3y "\tv3z="v3z
    print "#dbg: v4x="v4x "\tv4y=" v4y "\tv4z="v4z
  }

  plane1_x=(v1y*v2z)-(v1z*v2y)  # normal vector 1
  plane1_y=(v2x*v1z)-(v2z*v1x)  # normal vector 1
  plane1_z=(v1x*v2y)-(v1y*v2x)  # normal vector 1
  plane2_x=(v3y*v4z)-(v3z*v4y)  # normal vector 2
  plane2_y=(v4x*v3z)-(v4z*v3x)  # normal vector 2
  plane2_z=(v3x*v4y)-(v3y*v4x)  # normal vector 2
  if (dbg) {
    print "#dbg: plane1_x=" plane1_x "\tplane1_y=" plane1_y "\tplane1_z=" plane1_z
    print "#dbg: plane2_x=" plane2_x "\tplane2_y=" plane2_y "\tplane2_z=" plane2_z
  }

  v1mag=sqrt(((plane1_x)**2)+((plane1_y)**2)+((plane1_z)**2)) # magnitude normal vector 1
  v2mag=sqrt(((plane2_x)**2)+((plane2_y)**2)+((plane2_z)**2)) # magnitude normal vector 2
  if (dbg) {
    print "#dbg: v1mag=" v1mag "\tv2mag="v2mag
  }

  vn1x=(plane1_x)/(v1mag) ; vn1y=(plane1_y)/(v1mag) ; vn1z=(plane1_z)/(v1mag) # normalization normal vector 1
  vn2x=(plane2_x)/(v2mag) ; vn2y=(plane2_y)/(v2mag) ; vn2z=(plane2_z)/(v2mag) # normalization normal vector 2

  if (dbg) {
    print "#dbg: " (vn1x*vn2x) " "  (vn1y*vn2y)  " " ((vn1z*vn2z)*180/3.141592653589793)
  }
  print acos((vn1x*vn2x)+(vn1y*vn2y)+(vn1z*vn2z))*180/3.141592653589793
}
```

---

And here is the transcribed shell to awk version

I highly recommend the [Grymoire's Awk Tutorial](http://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) to help you understand the `awk` programming paradigm and its built in variables like `NR` (Number (of) Record).

```
cat torsion2_docd.awk
#!/bin/awk -f

function acos(x)  { return atan2((1.-x^2)^0.5,x) }

# x1=`awk '{print $2}' LINEA` # x1
# y1=`awk '{print $3}' LINEA` # y1
# z1=`awk '{print $4}' LINEA` # z1
# x2=`awk '{print $2}' LINEB` # x2
# y2=`awk '{print $3}' LINEB` # y2
# z2=`awk '{print $4}' LINEB` # z2
# x3=`awk '{print $2}' LINEC` # x3
# y3=`awk '{print $3}' LINEC` # y3
# z3=`awk '{print $4}' LINEC` # z3
# x4=`awk '{print $2}' LINED` # x4
# y4=`awk '{print $3}' LINED` # y4
# z4=`awk '{print $4}' LINED` # z4
NR==1 {x1=$2; y1=$3; z1=$4}
NR==2 {x2=$2; y2=$3; z2=$4}
NR==3 {x3=$2; y3=$3; z3=$4}
NR==4 {
  x4=$2; y=$3; z4=$4

  # all of this code below is only executed when you read in the 4th line
  # because then you have all the data
  #
  # v1x=`calc "($x2)-($x1)" | sed 's/^\t//g'` #plane1
  # v1y=`calc "($y2)-($y1)" | sed 's/^\t//g'` #plane1
  # v1z=`calc "($z2)-($z1)" | sed 's/^\t//g'` #plane1
  # v2x=`calc "($x3)-($x2)" | sed 's/^\t//g'` #plane1
  # v2y=`calc "($y3)-($y2)" | sed 's/^\t//g'` #plane1
  # v2z=`calc "($z3)-($z2)" | sed 's/^\t//g'` #plane1
  # v3x=`calc "($x2)-($x3)" | sed 's/^\t//g'` #plane2
  # v3y=`calc "($y2)-($y3)" | sed 's/^\t//g'` #plane2
  # v3z=`calc "($z2)-($z3)" | sed 's/^\t//g'` #plane2
  # v4x=`calc "($x3)-($x4)" | sed 's/^\t//g'` #plane2
  # v4y=`calc "($y3)-($y4)" | sed 's/^\t//g'` #plane2
  # v4z=`calc "($z3)-($z4)" | sed 's/^\t//g'` #plane2

  v1x=x2-x1 ; v1y=y2-y1 ; v1z=z2-z1     #plane1
  v2x=x3-x2 ; v2y=y3-y2 ; v2z=z3-z2     #plane1
  v3x=x2-x3 ; v3y=y2-y3 ; v3z=z2-z3     #plane2
  v1x=x2-x1 ; v1y=y2-y1 ; v1z=z2-z1     #plane1
  v2x=x3-x2 ; v2y=y3-y2 ; v2z=z3-z2     #plane1
  v3x=x2-x3 ; v3y=y2-y3 ; v3z=z2-z3     #plane2
  v4x=x3-x4 ; v4y=y3-y4 ; v4z=z3-z4     #plane2 

  # plane1_x=`calc "($v1y)*($v2z)-($v1z)*($v2y)" | sed 's/^\t//g'` # normal vector 1
  # plane1_y=`calc "($v2x)*($v1z)-($v2z)*($v1x)" | sed 's/^\t//g'` # normal vector 1
  # plane1_z=`calc "($v1x)*($v2y)-($v1y)*($v2x)" | sed 's/^\t//g'` # normal vector 1
  # plane2_x=`calc "($v3y)*($v4z)-($v3z)*($v4y)" | sed 's/^\t//g'` # normal vector 2
  # plane2_y=`calc "($v4x)*($v3z)-($v4z)*($v3x)" | sed 's/^\t//g'` # normal vector 2
  # plane2_z=`calc "($v3x)*($v4y)-($v3y)*($v4x)" | sed 's/^\t//g'` # normal vector 2

  plane1_x=(v1y*v2z)-(v1z*v2y)  # normal vector 1
  plane1_y=(v2x*v1z)-(v2z*v1x)  # normal vector 1
  plane1_z=(v1x*v2y)-(v1y*v2x)  # normal vector 1
  plane2_x=(v3y*v4z)-(v3z*v4y)  # normal vector 2
  plane2_y=(v4x*v3z)-(v4z*v3x)  # normal vector 2
  plane2_z=(v3x*v4y)-(v3y*v4x)  # normal vector 2

  # v1mag=`calc "sqrt(($plane1_x)**2+($plane1_y)**2+($plane1_z)**2)" | sed 's/^\t//g'`  # magnitude normal vector 1
  # v2mag=`calc "sqrt(($plane2_x)**2+($plane2_y)**2+($plane2_z)**2)" | sed 's/^\t//g'`  # magnitude normal vector 2

  v1mag=sqrt((plane1_x)**2+(plane1_y)**2+(plane1_z)**2) # magnitude normal vector 1
  v2mag=sqrt((plane2_x)**2+(plane2_y)**2+(plane2_z)**2) # magnitude normal vector 2

  # vn1x=`calc "($plane1_x)/($v1mag)" | sed 's/^\t//g'`  # normalization normal vector 1
  # vn1y=`calc "($plane1_y)/($v1mag)" | sed 's/^\t//g'`  # normalization normal vector 1
  # vn1z=`calc "($plane1_z)/($v1mag)" | sed 's/^\t//g'`  # normalization normal vector 1
  # vn2x=`calc "($plane2_x)/($v2mag)" | sed 's/^\t//g'`  # normalization normal vector 2
  # vn2y=`calc "($plane2_y)/($v2mag)" | sed 's/^\t//g'`  # normalization normal vector 2
  # vn2z=`calc "($plane2_z)/($v2mag)" | sed 's/^\t//g'`  # normalization normal vector 2

  vn1x=(plane1_x)/(v1mag) ; vn1y=(plane1_y)/(v1mag) ; vn1z=(plane1_z)/(v1mag) # normalization normal vector 1
  vn2x=(plane2_x)/(v2mag) ; vn2y=(plane2_y)/(v2mag) ; vn2z=(plane2_z)/(v2mag) # normalization normal vector 2

  # calc "acos(($vn1x)*($vn2x)+($vn1y)*($vn2y)+($vn1z)*($vn2z))*180/3.141592653589793" | sed 's/^\t//g' | sed 's/^~//g'

  print acos((vn1x*vn2x)+(vn1y*vn2y)+(vn1z*vn2z))*180/3.141592653589793
}
```

Comment: the difference is big, more practical, thank you so much for all your time and patience, good day

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT:** If your internet search for `torsion.awk` has brought you here, just skip up above to the accepted answer, as it uses the O.P.s refined algorithm to calculate torsion but still demonstrates converting shell code to `awk`.

Previous readers, also note improvements to using this code in the 2nd **edit** below.

---

*I Just noticed the "properly" qualifcation at the end ;-/*

Here's your code converted to one awk process.

I have no experience with this level of math, so can't say that it is really calculating the result you need.

Also, there are often questions about precision in awk programs which really relates to the underlying `c` language libraries that are compiled in.

Anyway, with all of the caveats, here's an basic conversion of your code.

cat torsion_docd.awk

```
#!/bin/awk -f

function acos(x)        { return atan2((1.-x^2)^0.5,x) }

# x1=`awk '{print $2}' LINEA` # x1
# y1=`awk '{print $3}' LINEA` # y1
# z1=`awk '{print $4}' LINEA` # z1
# x2=`awk '{print $2}' LINEB` # x2
# y2=`awk '{print $3}' LINEB` # y2
# z2=`awk '{print $4}' LINEB` # z2
# x3=`awk '{print $2}' LINEC` # x3
# y3=`awk '{print $3}' LINEC` # y3
# z3=`awk '{print $4}' LINEC` # z3
# x4=`awk '{print $2}' LINED` # x4
# y4=`awk '{print $3}' LINED` # y4
# z4=`awk '{print $4}' LINED` # z4
NR==1 {x1=$2; y=$3; z1=$4}
NR==2 {x2=$2; y=$3; z2=$4}
NR==3 {x3=$2; y=$3; z3=$4}
NR==4 {
        x4=$2; y=$3; z4=$4

        # all of this code below is only executed when you read in the 4th line
        # becuase then you have all the data
        # v1x=`calc "($x1)-($x2)" | sed 's/^\t//g'`
        # v1y=`calc "($y1)-($y2)" | sed 's/^\t//g'`
        # v1z=`calc "($z1)-($z2)" | sed 's/^\t//g'`
        # v2x=`calc "($x4)-($x3)" | sed 's/^\t//g'`
        # v2y=`calc "($y4)-($y3)" | sed 's/^\t//g'`
        # v2z=`calc "($z4)-($z3)" | sed 's/^\t//g'`

        v1x=x1-x2 ; v1y=y1-y2 ; v1z=z1-z2
        v2x=x4-x3 ; v2y=y4-y3 ; v2z=z4-z3

        # v1mag=`calc "sqrt(($v1x)**2+($v1y)**2+($v1z)**2)" | sed 's/^\t//g'`
        # v2mag=`calc "sqrt(($v2x)**2+($v2y)**2+($v2z)**2)" | sed 's/^\t//g'`

        v1mag=sqrt((v1x)**2+(v1y)**2+(v1z)**2)
        v2mag=sqrt((v2x)**2+(v2y)**2+(v2z)**2)   

        # calc "acos((($v1x)/($v1mag))*(($v2x)/($v2mag))+(($v1y)/($v1mag))*(($v2y)/($v2mag))+(($v1z)/($v1mag))*(($v2z)/($v2mag)))*180/3.141
592653589793" | sed 's/^\t//g' | sed 's/^~//g'
        # calc "acos((($x1)*($x4)+($y1)*($y4)+($z1)*($z4))/(sqrt(($x1)**2+($y1)**2+($z1)**2)*sqrt(($x4)**2+($y4)**2+($z4)**2)))*180/3.14159
2653589793" | sed 's/^\t//g' | sed 's/^~//g'

        print acos(((v1x)/(v1mag))*((v2x)/(v2mag))+((v1y)/(v1mag))*((v2y)/(v2mag))+((v1z)/(v1mag))*((v2z)/(v2mag)))*180/3.141592653589793
        print acos(((x1)*(x4)+(y1)*(y4)+(z1)*(z4))/(sqrt((x1)**2+(y1)**2+(z1)**2)*sqrt((x4)**2+(y4)**2+(z4)**2)))*180/3.141592653589793
}
```

And without the conversion documentation, it looks like

cat torsion.awk

```
#!/bin/awk -f

function acos(x)        { return atan2((1.-x^2)^0.5,x) }

NR==1 {x1=$2; y=$3; z1=$4}
NR==2 {x2=$2; y=$3; z2=$4}
NR==3 {x3=$2; y=$3; z3=$4}
NR==4 {
        x4=$2; y=$3; z4=$4

        # all of this code below is only executed when you read in the 4th line
        # because then you have all the data

        v1x=x1-x2 ; v1y=y1-y2 ; v1z=z1-z2
        v2x=x4-x3 ; v2y=y4-y3 ; v2z=z4-z3

        v1mag=sqrt((v1x)**2+(v1y)**2+(v1z)**2)
        v2mag=sqrt((v2x)**2+(v2y)**2+(v2z)**2)   

        print acos(((v1x)/(v1mag))*((v2x)/(v2mag))+((v1y)/(v1mag))*((v2y)/(v2mag))+((v1z)/(v1mag))*((v2z)/(v2mag)))*180/3.141592653589793
        print acos(((x1)*(x4)+(y1)*(y4)+(z1)*(z4))/(sqrt((x1)**2+(y1)**2+(z1)**2)*sqrt((x4)**2+(y4)**2+(z4)**2)))*180/3.141592653589793
}
```

Note that I added print statements in front of your last 2 lines `acos`.

On my machine, I run it as

```
awk -f torsion.awk data.txt
```

**EDIT** : I've fixed `#!/bin/awk` at the top of script. So you then need to mark the script as executable with

```
 chmod +x ./torsion.awk
```

And then you can run it just as

```
`./torsion.awk data.txt
```

Your system may require a different path to `awk` as in the she-bang line at the top (`#!/bin/awk`). Type `which awk`, and then use that value after the `#!`. Also, legacy Unix implementations often have other versions of `awk` installed, so if that is your operating environment, do some research to find out which is the best `awk` on your system (often times it is `gawk`).

```
# -------------- end edit --------------------
```

**output**

```
87.6318
131.872
```

But given you agreed that `-58.7` is your desired output, I'll have leave it to you for how to use the 2 `acos` calculations.

In any case, hopefully you can see how much more straight forward is is to use `awk` for such calculations.

Of course, hoping that true mathheads to wade in (after a good laugh) and help correct this (or offer their own ideas).

IHTH

Comment: Thank you, awk indeed is very practical.

Answer (score 1):

After a long night, I found the solution:

```
awk -v var=$((x+2)) 'NR==var' $FILE > LINEaa
awk -v var=$((y+2)) 'NR==var' $FILE > LINEbb
awk -v var=$((z+2)) 'NR==var' $FILE > LINEcc
awk -v var=$((w+2)) 'NR==var' $FILE > LINEd
x1=`awk '{print $2}' LINEaa` # x1
y1=`awk '{print $3}' LINEaa` # y1
z1=`awk '{print $4}' LINEaa` # z1
x2=`awk '{print $2}' LINEbb` # x2
y2=`awk '{print $3}' LINEbb` # y2
z2=`awk '{print $4}' LINEbb` # z2
x3=`awk '{print $2}' LINEcc` # x3
y3=`awk '{print $3}' LINEcc` # y3
z3=`awk '{print $4}' LINEcc` # z3
x4=`awk '{print $2}' LINEd` # x4
y4=`awk '{print $3}' LINEd` # y4
z4=`awk '{print $4}' LINEd` # z4
v1x=`calc "($x2)-($x1)" | sed 's/^\t//g'` #plane1
v1y=`calc "($y2)-($y1)" | sed 's/^\t//g'` #plane1
v1z=`calc "($z2)-($z1)" | sed 's/^\t//g'` #plane1
v2x=`calc "($x3)-($x2)" | sed 's/^\t//g'` #plane1
v2y=`calc "($y3)-($y2)" | sed 's/^\t//g'` #plane1
v2z=`calc "($z3)-($z2)" | sed 's/^\t//g'` #plane1
v3x=`calc "($x2)-($x3)" | sed 's/^\t//g'` #plane2
v3y=`calc "($y2)-($y3)" | sed 's/^\t//g'` #plane2
v3z=`calc "($z2)-($z3)" | sed 's/^\t//g'` #plane2
v4x=`calc "($x3)-($x4)" | sed 's/^\t//g'` #plane2
v4y=`calc "($y3)-($y4)" | sed 's/^\t//g'` #plane2
v4z=`calc "($z3)-($z4)" | sed 's/^\t//g'` #plane2
plane1_x=`calc "($v1y)*($v2z)-($v1z)*($v2y)" | sed 's/^\t//g'` # normal vector 1
plane1_y=`calc "($v2x)*($v1z)-($v2z)*($v1x)" | sed 's/^\t//g'` # normal vector 1
plane1_z=`calc "($v1x)*($v2y)-($v1y)*($v2x)" | sed 's/^\t//g'` # normal vector 1
plane2_x=`calc "($v3y)*($v4z)-($v3z)*($v4y)" | sed 's/^\t//g'` # normal vector 2
plane2_y=`calc "($v4x)*($v3z)-($v4z)*($v3x)" | sed 's/^\t//g'` # normal vector 2
plane2_z=`calc "($v3x)*($v4y)-($v3y)*($v4x)" | sed 's/^\t//g'` # normal vector 2
v1mag=`calc "sqrt(($plane1_x)**2+($plane1_y)**2+($plane1_z)**2)" | sed 's/^\t//g'`  # magnitude normal vector 1
v2mag=`calc "sqrt(($plane2_x)**2+($plane2_y)**2+($plane2_z)**2)" | sed 's/^\t//g'`  # magnitude normal vector 2
vn1x=`calc "($plane1_x)/($v1mag)" | sed 's/^\t//g'`  # normalization normal vector 1
vn1y=`calc "($plane1_y)/($v1mag)" | sed 's/^\t//g'`  # normalization normal vector 1
vn1z=`calc "($plane1_z)/($v1mag)" | sed 's/^\t//g'`  # normalization normal vector 1
vn2x=`calc "($plane2_x)/($v2mag)" | sed 's/^\t//g'`  # normalization normal vector 2
vn2y=`calc "($plane2_y)/($v2mag)" | sed 's/^\t//g'`  # normalization normal vector 2
vn2z=`calc "($plane2_z)/($v2mag)" | sed 's/^\t//g'`  # normalization normal vector 2
calc "acos(($vn1x)*($vn2x)+($vn1y)*($vn2y)+($vn1z)*($vn2z))*180/3.141592653589793" | sed 's/^\t//g' | sed 's/^~//g'
```

Comment: Hi @AnotherChemist : I've transcribed your final solution to a single process `awk` script, and added `print` in front of the final line with `acos(...)`. What is the result you get from your 4 lines of data in your Q? I'm getting zero and I don't suppose that is right. If I know what the target is, I'll debug some more and post an update to your update.

Comment: @AnotherChemist : OK, I've make progress, but I'm getting a `+58.6892` not the negative value. Did you confirm that  you need/want/expect the negative value? I'll be posting my transcription in the next day or two, fixed or not. Hopefully the more math-abled can point out my error. Good luck to all.

Comment: @shellter Hi! the math is easy, there are four consecutive points. There are two planes, the first is formed by points 1, 2 and 3. The second plane is formed by points 2, 3 and 4. Then, you obtain the normal vector of each plane through the cross product. Finally, you obtain the angle between those normal vectors.