# How to know if a dihedral angle is + or -?

Tags: geometry, angle

In several posts [post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46651542/bash-dihedral-angle-with-four-points/46831168#46831168) and [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46651542/bash-dihedral-angle-with-four-points) have been shared how to obtain a dihedral angle with four points or their two planes. But ... How can one know if that dihedral angle is positive or negative?

- What I have in mind to clasify them is the following diagram:

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a Math question. Nothing directly related to computer programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about geometry and [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate [triple product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product) of vectors P1P2, P2P3 and P3P4.

Sign of the value of this triple product shows handedness of vector triplet (right-handed or left-handed) and corresponds to the sign of dihedral angle

Comment: yes, thank you, i have figured out some seconds ago, +1