# What are the meanings of subscripts passed to numpy.einsum()?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-einsum

I am trying to understand a python code, which uses `numpy.einsum()` to convert a 4-dimensional numpy array, `A`, to 2- or 3-dimensional arrays. The subscripts passed to `numpy.einsum()` are as follows:

```
Mat1 = np.einsum('aabb->ab', A) 

Mat2 = np.einsum('abab->ab', A)

Mat3 = np.einsum('abba->ab', A) 

T1 = np.einsum('abcb->abc' A)

T2 = np.einsum('abbc->abc', A)
```

etc. Following the answers of ([Understanding NumPy's einsum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089893/understanding-numpys-einsum)) and ([Python - Sum 4D Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24841306/python-sum-4d-array)) I tried to use `numpy.sum()` to understand the meanings of the above subscripts, for example, `Mat1 = np.sum(A, axis=(0,3))` but I could not reproduce the results, which I get with `numpy.einsum()`.
Can someone please explain how these subscripts are interpreted in `numpy.einsum()` ?

Comment: These are all variations on a diagonal (or diagonals).  With a 4d array, you can take many kinds of diagonals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I advise you to read [Einstein notation on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation).

Here's a short answer to your question:

```
np.einsum('aabb->ab', A)
```

means:

```
res = np.empty((max_a, max_b), dtype=A.dtype)
for a in range(max_a):
  for b in range(max_b):
    res[a, b] = A[a, a, b, b]
return res
```

Short explanation:
`aabb` means the indexes and their equality (see `A[a, a, b, b]`);
`->ab` means the shape is `(max_a, max_b)` and you don't need two have sum on these two indexes. (if their were `c` also then you should sum everything by `c` as it is not presented after `->`)

---

Other your examples:

```
np.einsum('abab->ab', A)

# Same as (by logic, not by actual code)

res = np.empty((max_a, max_b), dtype=A.dtype)
for a in range(max_a):
  for b in range(max_b):
    res[a, b] = A[a, b, a, b]
return res
```

```
np.einsum('abba->ab', A) 

# Same as (by logic, not by actual code)

res = np.empty((max_a, max_b), dtype=A.dtype)
for a in range(max_a):
  for b in range(max_b):
    res[a, b] = A[a, b, b, a]
return res
```

```
np.einsum('abcb->abc', A)

# Same as (by logic, not by actual code)

res = np.empty((max_a, max_b, max_c), dtype=A.dtype)
for a in range(max_a):
  for b in range(max_b):
    for c in range(max_c):
      res[a, b, c] = A[a, b, c, b]
return res
```

```
np.einsum('abbc->abc', A)

# Same as (by logic, not by actual code)

res = np.empty((max_a, max_b, max_c), dtype=A.dtype)
for a in range(max_a):
  for b in range(max_b):
    for c in range(max_c):
      res[a, b, c] = A[a, b, b, c]
return res
```

Some code to check that it is actually true:

```
import numpy as np


max_a = 2
max_b = 3
max_c = 5

shape_1 = (max_a, max_b, max_c, max_b)
A = np.arange(1, np.prod(shape_1) + 1).reshape(shape_1)

print(A)
print()
print(np.einsum('abcb->abc', A))
print()

res = np.empty((max_a, max_b, max_c), dtype=A.dtype)
for a in range(max_a):
  for b in range(max_b):
    for c in range(max_c):
      res[a, b, c] = A[a, b, c, b]

print(res)
print()
```

Comment: Thank you very much @ CrafterKolyan