# How does architecture affect numpy array operation performance?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, intel-mkl, numpy-einsum

I have Ubuntu 14.04 with an "Anaconda" Python distribution with Intel's math kernel library (MKL) installed.  My processor is an Intel Xeon with 8 cores and without Hyperthreading (so only 8 threads).

For me numpy `tensordot` consistently outperforms `einsum` for large arrays.  However, others have found [very little difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30644968/write-double-triple-sum-as-inner-product/31186925#31186925) between the two or even that [einsum may outperform numpy for some operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365073/why-is-numpys-einsum-faster-than-numpys-built-in-functions/18365665#18365665).

For people with a `numpy` distribution built with a fast library, I am wondering why this might happen.    Does MKL run more slowly on non-Intel processors?  Or does `einsum` run faster on more modern Intel processors with better threading capabilities?

Here is a quick example code to compare performance on my machine:

```
In  [27]: a = rand(100,1000,2000)

In  [28]: b = rand(50,1000,2000)

In  [29]: time cten = tensordot(a, b, axes=[(1,2),(1,2)])
CPU times: user 7.85 s, sys: 29.4 ms, total: 7.88 s
Wall time: 1.08 s

In  [30]: "FLOPS TENSORDOT: {}.".format(cten.size * 1000 * 2000 / 1.08)
Out [30]: 'FLOPS TENSORDOT: 9259259259.26.'

In  [31]: time cein = einsum('ijk,ljk->il', a, b)
CPU times: user 42.3 s, sys: 7.58 ms, total: 42.3 s
Wall time: 42.4 s

In  [32]: "FLOPS EINSUM: {}.".format(cein.size * 1000 * 2000 / 42.4)
Out [32]: 'FLOPS EINSUM: 235849056.604.'
```

Tensor operations with tensordot run consistently in the 5-20 GFLOP range.  I only get 0.2 GFLOPS with einsum.

Comment: "einsum may outperform numpy for some operations."  That comparison is not valid. einsum is a very generic function, that can be used for a number of operations. You can't compare, say, simply copying an array with einsum with the complexity of a tensor product.

Comment: True.  I was interested in comparing the efficiency of `einsum` for tensor products that could also be done using `tensordot`.  That comparison does have some other comparisons which are a bit off topic here.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially you are comparing two very different things:

- `np.einsum` calculates the tensor product with `for` loops in C. It has has some SIMD optimizations but is not multi-threaded and does not use MLK.
- `np.tensordot`, which consists in reshaping/broadcasting the input arrays and then calling BLAS (MKL, OpenBLAS, etc) for the matrix multiplication.  The reshaping/broadcasting phase result in some additional overhead, however the  [matrix multiplication is extremely well optimized](https://store.continuum.io/static/img/mkl2.png) with SIMD, some assembler and multi-threading.

As a result, `tensordot` [will be generally faster  than  `einsum`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30645430/1791279) in single core execution, unless small  array sizes are used (and then the reshaping/broadcasting overhead becomes non negligible).  This is  even more true since the former approach is multi-threaded, while the later is not.

In conclusion, the results you are getting are perfectly normal and would probably be generally true (Intel/non-Intel CPU, modern or not, multi-core or not, using MKL or OpenBLAS, etc).