# Exterior product in NumPy : Vectorizing six nested loops

Tags: python, performance, numpy, vectorization

In a research paper, the author introduces an exterior product between two (3*3) matrices `A` and `B`, resulting in `C`:

```
C(i, j) = sum(k=1..3, l=1..3, m=1..3, n=1..3) eps(i,k,l)*eps(j,m,n)*A(k,m)*B(l,n)
```

where `eps(a, b, c)` is the [Levi-Civita symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol).

I am wondering how to vectorize such a mathematical operator in Numpy instead of implementing 6 nested loops (for `i, j, k, l, m, n`) naively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like a purely sum-reduction based problem without the requirement of keeping any axis aligned between the inputs. So, I would suggest matrix-multiplication based solution for tensors using [`np.tensordot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html).

Thus, one solution could be implemented in three steps -

```
# Matrix-multiplication between first eps and A.
# Thus losing second axis from eps and first from A : k 
parte1 = np.tensordot(eps,A,axes=((1),(0)))

# Matrix-multiplication between second eps and B.
# Thus losing third axis from eps and second from B : n
parte2 = np.tensordot(eps,B,axes=((2),(1)))

# Finally, we are left with two products : ilm & jml. 
# We need to lose lm and ml from these inputs respectively to get ij. 
# So, we need to lose last two dims from the products, but flipped .
out = np.tensordot(parte1,parte2,axes=((1,2),(2,1)))
```

**Runtime test**

Approaches -

```
def einsum_based1(eps, A, B):  # @unutbu's soln1
    return np.einsum('ikl,jmn,km,ln->ij', eps, eps, A, B)

def einsum_based2(eps, A, B):  # @unutbu's soln2
    return np.einsum('ilm,jml->ij',
              np.einsum('ikl,km->ilm', eps, A), 
              np.einsum('jmn,ln->jml', eps, B))

def tensordot_based(eps, A, B):
    parte1 = np.tensordot(eps,A,axes=((1),(0)))
    parte2 = np.tensordot(eps,B,axes=((2),(1)))
    return np.tensordot(parte1,parte2,axes=((1,2),(2,1)))
```

Timings -

```
In [5]: # Setup inputs
   ...: N = 20
   ...: eps = np.random.rand(N,N,N)
   ...: A = np.random.rand(N,N)
   ...: B = np.random.rand(N,N)
   ...: 

In [6]: %timeit einsum_based1(eps, A, B)
1 loops, best of 3: 773 ms per loop

In [7]: %timeit einsum_based2(eps, A, B)
1000 loops, best of 3: 972 µs per loop

In [8]: %timeit tensordot_based(eps, A, B)
1000 loops, best of 3: 214 µs per loop
```

Bigger dataset -

```
In [12]: # Setup inputs
    ...: N = 100
    ...: eps = np.random.rand(N,N,N)
    ...: A = np.random.rand(N,N)
    ...: B = np.random.rand(N,N)
    ...: 

In [13]: %timeit einsum_based2(eps, A, B)
1 loops, best of 3: 856 ms per loop

In [14]: %timeit tensordot_based(eps, A, B)
10 loops, best of 3: 49.2 ms per loop
```

Comment: Ah yes, [tensordot is faster](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30644968/190597).

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) which implements [Einstein summation notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation):

```
C = np.einsum('ikl,jmn,km,ln->ij', eps, eps, A, B)
```

or [for better performance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20910319/190597), apply einsum to two arrays at a time:

```
C = np.einsum('ilm,jml->ij',
              np.einsum('ikl,km->ilm', eps, A), 
              np.einsum('jmn,ln->jml', eps, B))
```

---

`np.einsum` computes a sum of products.
The subscript specifier `'ikl,jmn,km,ln->ij'` tells `np.einsum` that

- the first `eps` has subcripts `i,k,l`,
- the second `eps` has subcripts `j,m,n`,
- `A` has subcripts `k,m`,
- `B` has subcripts `l,n`,
- the output array has subscripts `i,j`

Thus, the summation is over products of the form

```
eps(i,k,l) * eps(j,m,n) * A(k,m) * B(l,n)
```

All subscripts not in the output array are summed over.

Comment: Second one came pretty close, nice!

Comment: In Numpy 1.12 you can simply do: `C = np.einsum('ikl,jmn,km,ln->ij', eps, eps, A, B, optimize=True)`! Not quite generally available yet however.

Comment: I patched the einsum ellipsis several years ago, but they've made some big changes in this latest release.