# Calculating "generating functions" with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

In mathematics, a "generating function" is defined from a sequence of numbers `c0`, `c1`, `c2`, ..., `cn` by `c0+c1*x+c2*x^2 + ... + cn*x^n`.  These come as "moment generating functions", "probability generating functions" and various other types, depending on the source of the coefficient.

I have an array of the coefficients and I'd like a quick way to create the corresponding generating function.

I could do

```
import numpy as np
myArray = np.array([1,2,3,4])
x=0.2
sum([c*x**k for k,c in enumerate myArray])
```

or I could have an array having `c[k]` in the `k`th entry.  It seems there should be a fast numpy way to do this.

Unfortunately attempts to look this up are complicated by the fact that "generate" and "function" are common words in programming, as is the combination "generating function" so I haven't had any luck with search engines.

Comment: Why not search for "polynomials"?

Comment: You are only interested in evaluating the function for one value of ```x``` at a time?

Comment: @JohnColeman Good question - suppose it's because I'm actually dealing with truncations of infinite sums, so it didn't occur to me.

Comment: @wwii  that's correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
x = .2
coeffs = np.array([1,2,3,4])
```

Make an array of the degree of each term

```
degrees = np.arange(len(coeffs))
```

Raise `x` the each degree

```
terms = np.power(x, degrees)
```

Multiply the coefficients and sum

```
result = np.sum(coeffs*terms)

>>> coeffs
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> degrees
array([0, 1, 2, 3])
>>> terms
array([ 1.   ,  0.2  ,  0.04 ,  0.008])
>>> result
1.552
>>>
```

---

As a function:

```
def f(coeffs, x):
    degrees = np.arange(len(coeffs))
    terms = np.power(x, degrees)
    return np.sum(coeffs*terms)
```

---

Or simply us the [Numpy Polynomial Package](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.polynomials.package.html#polynomial-package)

```
from numpy.polynomial import Polynomial as P
p = P(coeffs)
result = p(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for performance, using [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) could be suggested too -

```
np.einsum('i,i->',myArray,x**np.arange(myArray.size))
```

Comment: @Joel This [`Why is numpy's einsum faster than numpy's built in functions?`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18365073/3293881) might give some insights on performance benefits with `np.einsum`. Though, in this case, since you are summing up elements only along one axis, the performance benefits over using `np.sum` might be marginal.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> coeffs = np.random.random(5)
>>> coeffs
array([ 0.70632473,  0.75266724,  0.70575037,  0.49293719,  0.66905641])
>>> x = np.random.random()
>>> x
0.7252944971757169
>>> powers = np.arange(0, coeffs.shape[0], 1)
>>> powers
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> result = coeffs * x ** powers
>>> result
array([ 0.70632473,  0.54590541,  0.37126147,  0.18807659,  0.18514853])
>>> np.sum(result)
1.9967167252487628
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `numpy`s `Polynomial` class is probably the easiest way.

```
from numpy.polynomial import Polynomial

coefficients = [1,2,3,4]
f = Polynomial( coefficients )
```

You can then use the object like any other function.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

print f( 0.2 )

x = np.linspace( -5, 5, 51 )
plt.plot( x , f(x) )
```