# Efficiently calculating sum of squared differences

Tags: python, performance, numpy, cython

This is a loop for extracting the RGB values of two images, and calculating the sum of squared differences across all three channels.
Running this code directly in my main.py takes 0.07 sec. The speed gets reduced to 1sec if I run it in this .pyx file instead. I have read about cdef the functions, but I have had no success of passing the arrays then. Any help on converting this function to cdef function would be appreciated. I really need this loop to go as fast as possible.

```
from cpython cimport array
import array
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

def fittnes(Orginal, Mutated):

    Fittnes = 0

    for x in range(0, 299):

        for y in range(0, 299):

            DeltaRed   = (Orginal[x][y][0] - Mutated[x][y][0])
            DeltaGreen = (Orginal[x][y][1] - Mutated[x][y][1])
            DeltaBlue  = (Orginal[x][y][2] - Mutated[x][y][2])

            Fittnes += (DeltaRed * DeltaRed + DeltaGreen * DeltaGreen + DeltaBlue * DeltaBlue)

    return Fittnes
```

My Main.py function call

```
 NewScore = cythona.fittnes(numpy.array(Orginal), numpy.array(MutatedImage))
```

Comment: where is your cython code?

Comment: this is the cython code. It gets called from my main.py

Comment: If the input arrays are NumPy arrays, you could just do `((Orginal - Mutated)**2).sum()` for super speed.

Comment: What does the (**2) mean

Comment: I don't see anything cython specific in your code but as Divakar recommends you can speed your code up significantly just using numpy alone

Comment: I need the difference of each color

Comment: @Funktiona `**2` means [`power of 2 or squared`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.power.html).

Comment: Tried the code and its sumer fast. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Got me interested to know about the speedup numbers, so I am posting this as a solution. So, as stated/discussed in the comments, if the inputs are NumPy arrays, you could use native NumPy tools, and in this case [`ndarray.sum()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.sum.html), like so -

```
out = ((Orginal - Mutated)**2).sum()
```

You can also use the very efficient [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html)  for the same task, like so -

```
sub = Orginal - Mutated
out = np.einsum('ijk,ijk->',sub,sub)
```

**Runtime tests**

Define functions -

```
def org_app(Orginal,Mutated):
    Fittnes = 0
    for x in range(0, Orginal.shape[0]):
        for y in range(0, Orginal.shape[1]):
            DR = (Orginal[x][y][0] - Mutated[x][y][0])
            DG = (Orginal[x][y][1] - Mutated[x][y][1])
            DB  = (Orginal[x][y][2] - Mutated[x][y][2])
            Fittnes += (DR * DR + DG * DG + DB * DB)
    return Fittnes

def einsum_based(Orginal,Mutated):
    sub = Orginal - Mutated
    return np.einsum('ijk,ijk->',sub,sub)

def dot_based(Orginal,Mutated): # @ali_m's suggestion
    sub = Orginal - Mutated
    return np.dot(sub.ravel(), sub.ravel())

def vdot_based(Orginal,Mutated):  # variant of @ali_m's suggestion
    sub = Orginal - Mutated
    return np.vdot(sub, sub)
```

Timings -

```
In [14]: M,N = 100,100
    ...: Orginal = np.random.rand(M,N,3)
    ...: Mutated = np.random.rand(M,N,3)
    ...: 

In [15]: %timeit org_app(Orginal,Mutated)
    ...: %timeit ((Orginal - Mutated)**2).sum()
    ...: %timeit einsum_based(Orginal,Mutated)
    ...: %timeit dot_based(Orginal,Mutated)
    ...: %timeit vdot_based(Orginal,Mutated)
    ...: 
10 loops, best of 3: 54.9 ms per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 112 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 69.8 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 86.2 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 85.3 µs per loop

In [16]: # Inputs
    ...: M,N = 1000,1000
    ...: Orginal = np.random.rand(M,N,3)
    ...: Mutated = np.random.rand(M,N,3)
    ...: 

In [17]: %timeit org_app(Orginal,Mutated)
    ...: %timeit ((Orginal - Mutated)**2).sum()
    ...: %timeit einsum_based(Orginal,Mutated)
    ...: %timeit dot_based(Orginal,Mutated)
    ...: %timeit vdot_based(Orginal,Mutated)
    ...: 
1 loops, best of 3: 5.49 s per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 63 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 23.9 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 24.9 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 24.9 ms per loop
```

Comment: ...or just `np.dot(sub.ravel(), sub.ravel())`

Comment: @ali_m Nice! That works too! Add that as a solution? Would like to add it into the benchmarks either way.

Comment: how fast is np.dot(sub.ravel(), sub.ravel()) compared to einsum_based?

Comment: @Funktiona Added in that alongwith `np.vdot` based one in the benchmarks, check it out.

Comment: ((Orginal - Mutated)**2).sum() and 
einsum_based(Orginal,Mutated)
does not give the same results

Comment: @Funktiona How different are those?

Comment: sum gives me 1000000000000+

Comment: @Funktiona Ah yes! I think if you aren't working with `float64`, the values with `np.einsum` would be different. What's your input datatype?

Comment: @Funktiona You can read up on value inconsistencies with `np.einsum` [`here`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18366008/3293881).

Comment: These return the color delta of all 3 combined. I need them to extract  rgb and compare them separate.

Comment: @Funktiona I am not sure what you mean by extracting RGB? Could you clarify further?