# How to speed up Python code using numpy?

Tags: python, performance, numpy

`Orginal` and `Mutated` are images.
I need to get the difference of each r,g,b separately. I got this code to work, but it is to slow. Any help on making this fast would be nice! :)

```
Orginal = np.asarray(Orginal).copy()
Mutated = np.asarray(Mutated).copy()    

Fittnes = 0

for x in range(0, 299):

    for y in range(0, 299):

        DeltaRed   = (Orginal[x][y][0] - Mutated[x][y][0])
        DeltaGreen = (Orginal[x][y][1] - Mutated[x][y][1])
        DeltaBlue  = (Orginal[x][y][2] - Mutated[x][y][2])

        Fittnes += (DeltaRed * DeltaRed + DeltaGreen * DeltaGreen + DeltaBlue * DeltaBlue)

return Fittnes
```

Comment: You want to redo python part? Because there is a way to speed-up numpy itself, using intel MKL https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/numpyscipy-with-intel-mkl

Comment: Got a better code. Any better solution would be helpfull

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux MKL would only be relevant for linear algebra ops, e.g. matrix products. Simple vectorized subtraction and summation are handled by numpy's internals rather than external libraries.

Answer (score 3):

It should be a whole lot faster if you didn't go the extra mile of zipping and then summing up each dimension instead of using numpy's sum function:

```
DeltaRed   = np.sum(OR) - np.sum(MR)
DeltaGreen = np.sum(OG) - np.sum(MG)
DeltaBlue = np.sum(OB) - np.sum(MB)
```

Comment: Any way to improve it more?

Comment: On my computer, this gives you at least a 100x speed improvement. For anything beyond I'd have to know abot your particular use case. If you're summing up the whole image, all additional improvements will be small.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach to do all those in one summation with [`ndarray.sum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.sum.html) -

```
DeltaRed, DeltaGreen, DeltaBlue = Orginal.sum((0,1)) - Mutated.sum((0,1))
```

Here's another with [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) and hopefully faster one, when working with `uint8` images -

```
org_diff = np.einsum('ijk->k',Orginal.astype('uint64'))
mut_diff = np.einsum('ijk->k',Mutated.astype('uint64'))
DeltaRed, DeltaGreen, DeltaBlue = org_diff - mut_diff
```

Comment: This gets me the total RGB changes, I need them to calculate the RGB difference for each pixel, and get the total RGB changes for all pixels combined.

Comment: @Funktiona ` RGB difference for each pixel` would be `Orginal - Mutated`, right? And `total RGB changes for all pixels combined` would be as listed in the solution?

Comment: Look my code bellow. They does not do the same as your solutions

Comment: @Funktiona What's the datatype of `Orginal` and `Mutated`?

Comment: they are numpy.asarray

Comment: @Funktiona That's not a datatype. You can find out the datatype with `Orginal.dtype` and `Mutated.dtype`.

Comment: @Funktiona I think when working with huge arrays, the solution with `np.einsum` would have inconsistencies, so might be a better idea to use the `.sum((0,1))` based approach instead.

Comment: What do you mean by "inconsistencies"

Comment: @Funktiona Output values being different.

Comment: Its still not what I want. This gets me the sum of all red combined in original - all red combined in mutated. What I want is to calculate the RGB difference for each pixel.
Lets say Original[10, 10] has the RGB [100, 100, 100]. And Mutated[10, 10] has the RGB [180, 180, 180]. The output for this pixel should me. ((100 - 180) * (100 - 180) + (100 - 180) * (100 - 180) + (100 - 180) * (100 - 180)). So I get a value on how similar the mutated pixel is compared to the Orginal. I need to multiply it by itself so I don’t get negative numbers

Comment: @Funktiona `((Orginal - Mutated)**2).sum((0,1))`?

Comment: If two pixels in Mutated swaps possession, don't I still get the same value? This is function decides the similarities between them. I need to compare them pixel for pixel, not just compare the total RGB difference.

Comment: @Funktiona If you have a for-loop code that works please edit the question.  Then, we can think of optimizing it.

Comment: @Funktiona The edited code is same as your [`previous question`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33709902/3293881) right? So, didn't the solution to that previous question work for you?

Comment: @Funktiona You did confirm on the previous question's solution that it worked with sum : `((Orginal - Mutated)**2).sum()`. Now , you are saying it's not working?

Comment: After some more testing I got that it diden't. Sorry

Comment: @Funktiona I think your code is wrong because as you said you are using `uint8` datatype and you are subtracting and multiplying, in which you are encountering overflows. It's getting too long with these conversations, so good luck, sorry can't help you any further as we are moving in circles here.

Answer (score 0):

This was the code from beginning that worked.

```
    Fittnes = 0

    for x in range(0, 299):

        for y in range(0, 299):

            DeltaRed   = (Orginal[x][y][0] - Mutated[x][y][0])
            DeltaGreen = (Orginal[x][y][1] - Mutated[x][y][1])
            DeltaBlue  = (Orginal[x][y][2] - Mutated[x][y][2])

            Fittnes += (DeltaRed * DeltaRed + DeltaGreen * DeltaGreen + DeltaBlue * DeltaBlue)

   return Fittnes
```