# Numpy: find the euclidean distance between two 3-D arrays

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, vectorization, euclidean-distance

Given, two 3-D arrays of dimensions (2,2,2):

```
A = [[[ 0,  0],
    [92, 92]],

   [[ 0, 92],
    [ 0, 92]]]

B = [[[ 0,  0],
    [92,  0]],

   [[ 0, 92],
    [92, 92]]]
```

How do you find the Euclidean distance for each vector in A and B efficiently?

I have tried for-loops but these are slow, and I'm working with 3-D arrays in the order of (>>2, >>2, 2).

Ultimately I want a matrix of the form:

```
C = [[d1, d2],
     [d3, d4]]
```

Edit:

I've tried the following loop, but the biggest issue with it is that loses the dimensions I want to keep. But the distances are correct.

```
[numpy.sqrt((A[row, col][0] - B[row, col][0])**2 + (B[row, col][1] -A[row, col][1])**2) for row in range(2) for col in range(2)]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thinking in a NumPy vectorized way that would be performing element-wise differentiation, squaring and summing along the last axis and finally getting square root. So, the straight-forward implementation would be -

```
np.sqrt(((A - B)**2).sum(-1))
```

We could perform the squaring and summing along the last axis in one go with [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) and thus make it more efficient, like so -

```
subs = A - B
out = np.sqrt(np.einsum('ijk,ijk->ij',subs,subs))
```

Another alternative with [`numexpr` module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numexpr) -

```
import numexpr as ne
np.sqrt(ne.evaluate('sum((A-B)**2,2)'))
```

Since, we are working with a length of `2` along the last axis, we could just slice those and feed it to `evaluate` method. Please note that slicing isn't possible inside the evaluate string. So, the modified implementation would be -

```
a0 = A[...,0]
a1 = A[...,1]
b0 = B[...,0]
b1 = B[...,1]
out = ne.evaluate('sqrt((a0-b0)**2 + (a1-b1)**2)')
```

**Runtime test**

Function definitions -

```
def sqrt_sum_sq_based(A,B):
    return np.sqrt(((A - B)**2).sum(-1))

def einsum_based(A,B):
    subs = A - B
    return np.sqrt(np.einsum('ijk,ijk->ij',subs,subs))

def numexpr_based(A,B):
    return np.sqrt(ne.evaluate('sum((A-B)**2,2)'))

def numexpr_based_with_slicing(A,B):
    a0 = A[...,0]
    a1 = A[...,1]
    b0 = B[...,0]
    b1 = B[...,1]
    return ne.evaluate('sqrt((a0-b0)**2 + (a1-b1)**2)')
```

Timings -

```
In [288]: # Setup input arrays
     ...: dim = 2
     ...: N = 1000
     ...: A = np.random.rand(N,N,dim)
     ...: B = np.random.rand(N,N,dim)
     ...: 

In [289]: %timeit sqrt_sum_sq_based(A,B)
10 loops, best of 3: 40.9 ms per loop

In [290]: %timeit einsum_based(A,B)
10 loops, best of 3: 22.9 ms per loop

In [291]: %timeit numexpr_based(A,B)
10 loops, best of 3: 18.7 ms per loop

In [292]: %timeit numexpr_based_with_slicing(A,B)
100 loops, best of 3: 8.23 ms per loop

In [293]: %timeit np.linalg.norm(A-B, axis=-1) #@dnalow's soln
10 loops, best of 3: 45 ms per loop
```

Comment: Would you have links or resources that compare `np.einsum` vs regular numpy efficiency ?

Comment: @jadsq I guess [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365073/why-is-numpys-einsum-faster-than-numpys-built-in-functions) if we are talking about a general case. On this specific case, we are doing two things in one go with `einsum` and that makes it really beneficial here.

Comment: @Divakar, thank you! I've learned again something new from you today.

Comment: numexpr is much faster with slicing. My arrays are quite large though: (8464, 8464, 2), and I find the computation still too slow.

Comment: @user1658296 How much time is it taking?

Comment: I'm getting approximately 2.5 seconds, which is far better than linalg which on average was taking ~ 13 seconds.

Comment: I have a vector of shape `(1,10,512)`, I need to calculate its euclidean from matrix of shape `(20000,1,512)`. The required shape `(20000,10)`. How do I use numexpr based slicing to my advantage?

Answer (score 5):

for completeness:

```
np.linalg.norm(A-B, axis=-1)
```

Comment: Nice! Added this to the list of approaches for runtime testing.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend being extremely careful when using custom squares and root instead of standard builtin math.hypot and np.hypot. These are fast and optimized and very safe.

In that sense `np.linalg.norm(A-B, axis=-1)` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40319768/7035448) looks safest

For very large matrices, numpy using broadcast will become memory bound and slowdown. In such cases you would want to use for loops but dont compromise on speed. For that using numba will be good [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68591676/why-np-hypot-and-np-subtract-outer-very-fast-compared-to-vanilla-broadcast-usi)

```py
i, j, k = 1e+200, 1e+200, 1e+200
math.hypot(i, j, k)
# 1.7320508075688773e+200
```

Refer: [speed/overflow/underflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69233528/7035448)

```py
np.sqrt(np.sum((np.array([i, j, k])) ** 2))
# RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in square
```