# numpy array of array adding up another array

Tags: numpy

I am having the following array of array

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]) 
b = np.array([[1,5,10])
```

and want to add up the value in b into a, like

```
np.array([[2,7,13],[5,10,16]])
```

what is the best approach with performance concern to achieve the goal?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Broadcasting does that for you, so:

```
>>> a+b
```

just works:

```
array([[ 2,  7, 13],
       [ 5, 10, 16]])
```

And it can also be done with

```
>>> a  + np.tile(b,(2,1))
```

which gives the result

```
array([[ 2,  7, 13],
       [ 5, 10, 16]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on size of inputs and time constraints, both methods might be of consideration

**Method 1: Numpy Broadcasting**

- Operation on two arrays are possible if they are compatible
- Operation generally done along with broadcasting
- broadcasting in lay man terms could be called repeating elements along a specified axis
- Conditions for broadcasting

  - Arrays need to be compatible
  - Compatibility is decided based on their shapes
  - shapes are compared from right to left.
  - from right to left while comparing, either they should be equal or one of them should be 1
  - smaller array is broadcasted(repeated) over bigger array

```py
a.shape, b.shape
((2, 3), (1, 3))
```

From the rules they are compatible, so they can be added, b is smaller, so b is repeated long 1 dimension, so b can be treated as [[ 5, 10, 16], [ 5, 10, 16]]. But note numpy does not allocate new memory, it is just view.

```py
a + b
```

```
array([[ 2,  7, 13],
       [ 5, 10, 16]])
```

**Method 2: Numba**

- Numba gives parallelism
- It will convert to optimized machine code
- Why this is because, sometimes numpy broadcasting is not good enough, ufuncs(np.add, np.matmul, etc) allocate temp memory during operations and it might be time consuming if already on memory limits
- Easy parallelization
- Using numba based on your requirement, you might not need temp memory allocation or various checks which numpy does, which can speed up code for huge inputs, for example. [Why are np.hypot and np.subtract.outer very fast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68591676/why-are-np-hypot-and-np-subtract-outer-very-fast)

```
import numba as nb

@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def sum(a, b):
    s = np.empty(a.shape, dtype=a.dtype)
    # nb.prange gives numba hint to what to parallelize
    for i in nb.prange(a.shape[0]):
        s[i] = a[i] + b
    return s
sum(a, b)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I have tried both method, the numba method seems like perform worse than the other one, with the A has got 100 elements. Am I right that numba would perform better when the size of A become very large?

Comment: I also have another question about filtering the array. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68860546/numpy-array-of-array-adding-up-another-array/68861371#68861371

Would there be also a solution in numba that would deal with large size of the array?

Comment: I mean like 10000000 elements, numba's first execution is always slow due to compilation. 100 is too small

Comment: I am talking about problems like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68591676/why-are-np-hypot-and-np-subtract-outer-very-fast

Comment: I gave numba version for filtering, you can check