# Calculations through for loop and through simple indexing

Tags: python

```
decay = 0.1
data = np.array([100,200,300,400,500])
y = np.zeros(len(data))

for i in range(len(data)):
    if i == 0:
        y[i] = (1.0 - decay) * data[i]

    else:
        y[i] = (1.0 - decay) * data[i] + (decay * y[i - 1])
        
y
```

Output:

```
array([ 90.   , 189.   , 288.9  , 388.89 , 488.889])
```

Now this I'm cut shorting by indexing

```
decay = 0.1
data = np.array([100,200,300,400,500])
data = (1.0 - decay) * data
data[1:] = data[1:] + decay * data[0:-1]
data
```

Output:

```
array([ 90., 189., 288., 387., 486.])
```

I feel here I'm doing some mistake or missing float values or not getting cumulative value as both the output aren't matching, the first output is the correct one, what is the mistake here?

Comment: Isn't this identical to your last question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69031699/calculation-on-my-for-loop-and-want-to-do-it-without-for-loop-using-some-functio

Comment: I see, you're asking what's the mistake. You can work out the math by hand and see that it doesn't match

Comment: For later indices in your array you are missing comulative terms. Those are small fractions of the cumsum of your array, because you multiply a number less than one (`decay = .1` -> for the second element `.1*.1 = .01`) with itself multiple times. [Kyle Parsons answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69032484/14277722) is still your best option to vectorize.

Comment: These are the terms you are missing: 288.9 = `288` + .01 * `90`, 388.89 = `387` + .01 * `189`, 488.889 = `486` + .01 * (`288` + .01 * `90`)

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny Yeah Kyle's answer is the best option but looking for something simple to understand too. I have found the terms missing but am unable to achieve how do I get those missing values like .01 *90, .01*189 etc.