# Custom dtype in numpy for lattitude, longitude for faster distance matrix/krigging/IDW interpolation calculations

Tags: python, performance, numpy, geospatial, numba

I have two 2-D Numpy arrays coordinates of points in latitude and longitude asc_cords and dsc_cords each of size (400000, 2) each.

I need to calculate distance matrix in fastest way possible.

Using vanilla numpy it was not possible to get speed up due to memory restrictions. So I decide to use numba ([Reference to my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68591676/why-np-hypot-and-np-subtract-outer-very-fast-compared-to-vanilla-broadcast-usi))

Presently I use something similar to this, and on 12 cores, 16GB it gives speedup from 40 minutes to 60s.

```py
@nb.njit((nb.float64[:, :], nb.float64[:, :]), parallel=True)
def f2(d0, d1):
    print('Numba with parallel')
    res = np.empty((d0.shape[0], d1.shape[0]), dtype=d0.dtype)
    for i in nb.prange(d0.shape[0]):
        for j in range(d1.shape[0]):
            res[i, j] = np.sqrt((d0[i, 0] - d1[j, 0])**2 + (d0[i, 1] - d1[j, 1])**2)
    return res
```

But I notice one more problem, I use for latitude and longitude np.float64 type

```py
np.finfo('float64')
# finfo(resolution=1e-15, min=-1.7976931348623157e+308, max=1.7976931348623157e+308, dtype=float64)
```

It is good that it has precision til 16 decimals, but 1e+308 is not desireable. Since Latitude, longitude vary between (-180, 180), e+308 is never attainable. I want to make a new numpy data type which has same precision as float64, but max in between (-e+6, 1e+6) hoping that it will significantly reduce computation time.

1. Am I on right track (like trying to make custom dtype) or is it not possible?(P.S. I am having trouble finding an article tackling simialr problem)
2. If I am, then how should I make a custom dtype in numpy or numba is also fine?

Comment: It is not possible. Double is defined by your hardware, if your hardware doesn’t have support for other floating point types you will not be able to use them efficiently.  I.E. your hardware is only able to multiply two normal doubles, multpliying other double types is possible but much more costly, as it must be emulated in software.

Comment: @ead If I approximate to float32 it speed up. Does that mean my hardware can support float32, float64 also? Also numpy has float16 also but I am not using them due to precision loss. I thought all of these are for faster speeds, am I correct?

Comment: Single precision (32bit) is also supported by the hardware nowdays. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/3426165/5769463. The advantage of single/half precision is that less memory is needed and that like sin and cos need less iterations.

Comment: Distance in spherical coordinates (lat, lon) can't be calculated using the Euclidean distance. You need to use the [great circle distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance) or [Vincenty's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty%27s_formulae).
Unless you only need to compare small distances, where the Euclidean distance might be an approximation. If, for example, you were interested in finding nearest neighbors, you could use the [flann](https://pypi.org/project/flann/) library instead of calculating a table of 160000000000 distances.

Comment: I am only comparing small distances....so please assume this is valid